# column does not belong to table Table

Tags: dataset

I don't know exactly where I have to look for.
Error is:

```
Column 'pkJudge' does not belong to table Table. '
   at System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName)
   at System.Data.DataRow.set_Item(String columnName, Object value)
   at ReadyCollect.CaseEntry.S_GetJudges(Int32 courtID)
   at ReadyCollect.CaseEntry.S_GetExistCaseInfo()
   at ReadyCollect.CaseEntry.CaseReminder_HoldCase()
   at ReadyCollect.CaseEntry.btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

It occurs in the following code fragment. Any Ideas?

```
Private Sub S_GetJudges(ByVal courtID As Integer)
    ' Load the list of judges   '
    Dim JudgeSet As New DataSet
    Dim dv As System.Data.DataView
    Dim DAl As New DataAccessLayer
    Dim pfkCourt As Integer = CourtDDL.SelectedValue

    If ClientKey > 0 And pfkCourt > 0 Then
        JudgeSet = DAl.GetJudgespkJudgesJudgeNamefkCourt(ClientKey, pfkCourt)
        JudgeDataTable = JudgeSet.Tables(0)
        Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
        dr = JudgeDataTable.NewRow()
        dr("pkJudge") = "0"
        dr("Judge Name") = "(Select a Judge)"
        JudgeDataTable.Rows.Add(dr)
        JudgeDDL.SelectedValue = 0
        JudgeDDL.DataSource = JudgeDataTable.DefaultView
        dv = JudgeDataTable.DefaultView
        dv.Sort ="pkJudge ASC"
        JudgeDDL.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

And the dataaccess method that is called in the code fragment is below.
Now `JudgeDataTable` is declared as
`Private JudgeDataTable As System.Data.DataTable` on top of the page.
Rest is in the code fragment as I posted above.

```
'Retreives fields pkJudge and [Judge Name] from the table Judges where field fkCourt is equal to fkCourt '

Public Function GetJudgespkJudgesJudgeNamefkCourt(ByVal ClientKey As Integer, ByVal fkCourt As Integer) As DataSet
    Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()
    Dim sqlCommand As String = "USP_DISPLAYJUDGESPKJUDGEJUDGENAMEFKCOURT"
    Dim dbCommand As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand)
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand,"ClientKey", DbType.Int32, ClientKey)
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand,"fkCourt", DbType.Int32, fkCourt)
    Return db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand)
End Function
```

Comment: Can you format your code by putting it between the <code> </code> tags?

Answer (score 0):

`Partial Class CaseEntry
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page`

```
     Private JudgeDataTable As System.Data.DataTable
       Private Sub S_GetJudges(ByVal courtID As Integer)

        ' Load the list of judges
        JudgeDataTable = New System.Data.DataTable
        Dim JudgeSet As New DataSet
        Dim dv As System.Data.DataView
        Dim DAl As New DataAccessLayer
        Dim pfkCourt As Integer = CourtDDL.SelectedValue
        If ClientKey > 0 And pfkCourt > 0 Then
            JudgeSet = DAl.GetJudgespkJudgesJudgeNamefkCourt(ClientKey, pfkCourt)
            JudgeDataTable = JudgeSet.Tables(0)
            Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
            dr = JudgeDataTable.NewRow()
            dr("pkJudge") = "0"
            dr("Judge Name") = "(Select a Judge)"
            JudgeDataTable.Rows.Add(dr)
            JudgeDDL.SelectedValue = 0
            JudgeDDL.DataSource = JudgeDataTable.DefaultView
            dv = JudgeDataTable.DefaultView
            dv.Sort = "pkJudge ASC"
            JudgeDDL.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub
```

`'Retreives fields pkJudge and [Judge Name] from the table Judges where field fkCourt is equal to fkCourt
    Public Function GetJudgespkJudgesJudgeNamefkCourt(ByVal ClientKey As Integer, ByVal fkCourt As Integer) As DataSet`

```
    Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()
    Dim sqlCommand As String = "USP_DISPLAYJUDGESPKJUDGEJUDGENAMEFKCOURT"
    Dim dbCommand As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand)

    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "ClientKey", DbType.Int32, ClientKey)
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "fkCourt", DbType.Int32, fkCourt)

    Return db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you break after the getdataset stuff and look at the datatable? Is the column there? Otherwise, maybe try to access it via column index.

Comment: If the column would'nt be there at all then it should throw error each time the page load. Hmm this comes like for few .How canI check the column existence.

Comment: Enumerate through the column collection on the table. That should tell you what's there.

Comment: I tried enumerating through the column Index , I see the column exists.